# Can I access Fb user details even without requesting the user to sign-in for an android app that I am developing

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Overall skeleton of the app goes like this,

The app opens, let's the new user to register or already existing user to login goes into SQLite. Later I want to fetch data from/through the user's profile. Is it possible?

I have been looking into this **AccessToken** stuff offered by Fb but everything flows over my head.

Let's say the user logs in initially by registering. Later I'll let the user to type in what to search and I want to fetch those search result from Facebook, those search results should *also* be from the user's profile. All these should happen even without the user manually entering his Fb details, rather he's going to get a pop up dialog box that says *Continue with Fb login* something of that sort.

Comment: can you add more detail to the question?

Comment: no user data without login

Answer (score 0):

Facebook user details only access with Access Token which is generated by facebook. First need to create developer account then create app over developer account. App ID and Key need to put on your android app which you can get from facebook developer account after creating an app there. For more details check out its official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you question states that you want to get the user detail from facebook without getting logged in you app.if that is the case yes it is possible. because getting details from facebook is a different process and you getting logged in your app is a different one.

```
private Context context;
private Fragment mFragment;
private ShareDialog mShareDialog;

/**
 * @param context
 */
public FacebookLoginManager(Context context, Fragment fragment) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mFragment = fragment;
}

/**
 * @param context
 */
public FacebookLoginManager(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

/**
 * The purpose of this method is to initialize the facebook sdk
 *
 * @param callbackManager
 */
public void initializedFacebook(CallbackManager callbackManager) {
    if (FacebookSdk.isInitialized()) {
        performFacebookLogin(callbackManager);
    } else {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        performFacebookLogin(callbackManager);
    }
}

/**
 * The purpose of this method is to initialize the facebook  data from the server
 *
 * @param callbackManager
 */
private void performFacebookLogin(CallbackManager callbackManager) {
    try {
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        final String accessToken = "" + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
                        Log.e("accessToken", accessToken);

                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {
                                        try {
                                            final FacebookResponseBean mFacebookResponseBean = new FacebookResponseBean();
                                            if (object != null) {
                                                if (object.has(FacebookConstants.ID) && object.get(FacebookConstants.ID) != null) {
                                                    mFacebookResponseBean.setUserId(object.get(FacebookConstants.ID) + "");
                                                }
                                                if (object.has(FacebookConstants.NAME) && object.get(FacebookConstants.NAME) != null) {
                                                    mFacebookResponseBean.setName(object.get(FacebookConstants.NAME) + "");
                                                }
                                                if (object.has(FacebookConstants.EMAIL) && object.get(FacebookConstants.EMAIL) != null) {
                                                    mFacebookResponseBean.setEmail(object.get(FacebookConstants.EMAIL) + "");
                                                }
                                                if (object.has(FacebookConstants.GENDER) && object.get(FacebookConstants.GENDER) != null) {
                                                    mFacebookResponseBean.setGender(object.get(FacebookConstants.GENDER) + "");
                                                }
                                                if (object.has(FacebookConstants.BIRTHDAY) && object.get(FacebookConstants.BIRTHDAY) != null) {
                                                    mFacebookResponseBean.setBirthday(object.get(FacebookConstants.BIRTHDAY) + "");
                                                }
                                                if (object.has(FacebookConstants.AGE_RANGE) && object.get(FacebookConstants.AGE_RANGE) != null) {
                                                    mFacebookResponseBean.setAgerange(object.get(FacebookConstants.AGE_RANGE) + "");
                                                }
                                                if (object.has(FacebookConstants.TIMEZONE) && object.get(FacebookConstants.TIMEZONE) != null) {
                                                    mFacebookResponseBean.setTimezone(object.get(FacebookConstants.TIMEZONE) + "");
                                                }
                                                if (object.has(FacebookConstants.VERIFIED) && object.get(FacebookConstants.VERIFIED) != null) {
                                                    mFacebookResponseBean.setVerified(object.get(FacebookConstants.VERIFIED) + "");
                                                }
                                                if (object.has(FacebookConstants.UPDATED_TIME) && object.get(FacebookConstants.UPDATED_TIME) != null) {
                                                    mFacebookResponseBean.setUpdatedtime(object.get(FacebookConstants.UPDATED_TIME) + "");
                                                }
                                                if (object.has(FacebookConstants.LOCALE) && object.get(FacebookConstants.LOCALE) != null) {
                                                    mFacebookResponseBean.setLocale(object.get(FacebookConstants.LOCALE) + "");
                                                }
                                                if (object.has(FacebookConstants.FIRST_NAME) && object.get(FacebookConstants.FIRST_NAME) != null) {
                                                    mFacebookResponseBean.setFirstName(object.get(FacebookConstants.FIRST_NAME) + "");
                                                }
                                                if (object.has(FacebookConstants.LAST_NAME) && object.get(FacebookConstants.LAST_NAME) != null) {
                                                    mFacebookResponseBean.setLastName(object.get(FacebookConstants.LAST_NAME) + "");
                                                }
                                                if (object.has(FacebookConstants.PICTURE) && object.get(FacebookConstants.PICTURE) != null) {
                                                    JSONObject picture = object.getJSONObject(FacebookConstants.PICTURE);
                                                    JSONObject data = picture.getJSONObject("data");
                                                    if (data.has("url") && data.get("url") != null) {
                                                        mFacebookResponseBean.setPhotolink(data.get("url") + "");
                                                        Logger.error("image", data.get("url") + "");
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            }
                                            if (context instanceof LoginActivity) {
                                                ((LoginActivity) context).setFaceBookResponse(mFacebookResponseBean);
                                            } else if (context instanceof RegistrationActivity) {
                                                ((RegistrationActivity) context).setFaceBookResponse(mFacebookResponseBean);
                                            } else if (context instanceof UserProfileActivity) {
                                                ((UserProfileActivity) context).setFaceBookResponse(mFacebookResponseBean);
                                            } else if (mFragment != null && mFragment instanceof FragmentLinkAccounts) {
                                                ((FragmentLinkAccounts) mFragment).setFaceBookResponse(mFacebookResponseBean);

                                            }
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", FacebookConstants.PERMISSION);
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                        if (exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException) {
                            if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * The purpose of this method is to share the image and content on facebook
 *
 * @param activity
 * @param manager
 * @param image
 * @param isShareRequest
 * @param id
 */
public void shareContent(final Activity activity, CallbackManager manager, View image, final boolean isShareRequest, int id) {
    mShareDialog = new ShareDialog(activity);
    String time = GlobalAcess.getDateTime();
    mShareDialog.registerCallback(manager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            if (isShareRequest)
                ToastMessage.getInstance(activity).showLongMessage(activity.getString(R.string.msg_request_posted));
            else
                ToastMessage.getInstance(activity).showLongMessage(activity.getString(R.string.msg_trip_posted));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            error.printStackTrace();

        }
    });
    String url = "";
    if (isShareRequest) {
        url = NetworkConstants.SHARE_REQUEST_URL + "id=" + id + "?t=" + time;
    } else {
        url = NetworkConstants.SHARE_TRIP_URL + "id=" + id + "?t=" + time;
    }
    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(url))
                .build();
        mShareDialog.show(content);
    }

}
```

}
//

Comment: // WAY TO MAKE A CALL TO  FACEBOOK
CallbackManager  mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        new FacebookLoginManager(this, fragment).initializedFacebook(mCallbackManager);

Dependency to be added in gradle 
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0'

Step by step procedure can be looked from here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/